# Laravel - Saving INT to database turns negative

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent

I'm saving some data to my database but there is one field which becomes negative when I save the data.

```
["invoice_id"]=> int(20210126075173)
```

This is taken from a `var_dump()` and is the number that I'm trying to save. This looks completely normal but when I look into the database I get the number

```
-1990019803
```

The thing is, when I run the code on my machine, it works like it's intended and saves the number as it should but when I do this on the actual server it returns that negative number. My local database is also a clone from the live database.

**"Invoice_id" is a varchar field** I tried changing it to **INT** or **BIGINT** but that makes no difference.

Comment: Try This ["invoice_id"]=> (int)20210126075173

Comment: That still gives me the same negative number...

Comment: 20210126075173 this is not integer this passes the limit of integer values. 
you should not cast it with int, and you should not store it in int column you may use big integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you change `invoice_id` from var_char field to int field? I think if it is varchar, you can add `""` to save into database.

Comment: Thank you! This was the answer in my case!

$invoice->invoice_id = "$invoice_id"; solved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can do several things to prevent this from happening:

1. make the database column a **UNSIGNED INTEGER** by using `$table->unsignedInteger('column name');`
2. Check the value before inserting to db with a **if** statement `( (int) ["invoice_id"] >= 0 ) ?? ["invoice_id"] * -1`

The problem of difference between your local and remote server might be related to the database server(mysql,postgrs,...) version or system locale.I have not seen this before and have no idea what is causing it.

Make sure to validate the data before inserting it into database to prevent unwanted values (which takes you to second option)

Answer (score 0):

Why are you looking to cast `["invoice_id"]=> int(20210126075173)` to an int, when it seems like you're already giving it an integer?

You could try:

`["invoice_id"]=> 20210126075173`

or if you're casting a string to an int:

`["invoice_id"]=> int() '20210126075173'`